# emailing url with uid

Tags: php, security, cakephp

I have a 2-step form. The second step is quite lengthly and the visitor may want to complete it at a later time. What I have done is generate a uid with sha1 using a combination of details: firstname, email address, salt and I email the visitor the link eg:

http://www.mysite.com/form/step2/[sha1 uid]

so when they click the links they can go back to the second step of the form...

I realize this isn't super secure, but is it acceptable? if not, what improvements can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your link is a bit random, people won't be able to "guess" it ; so, you should be OK, I suppose, as long as your "salt" is not the same for everyone *(I guess it's some kind of random data your generate for each user ?)*

Maybe you could have a "password" field on the first step of the form, and, if users arrive to the second step of the form via the link in the e-mail, they should re-type this password, to confirm they know it ?

I am not sure it is really necessary, but it might be seen by your users as a security measure (and some people like when the websites they are using are *(or, at least, look like)* secure).

Another nice thing to have would be for the link to be valid only a couple of days, maybe -- if that's suitable with the needs of your application.